# Where to get working Sysinternals tools for Windows 2000?

Tags: windows-2000, windows

Yes, I know Windows 2000 will run end-of-life in this year, but we still have a lot of Windows 2000 boxes we try to migrate but no idea if all of them can be migrated this year...

Recently I downloaded a new Sysinternals Suite (most recent file date `2010-03-25`) and noticed that some tools just do not work on Windows 2000 any longer, which makes troubleshooting a lot harder. I checked all the tools in the suite to check which tools do not work, and dug through to find older versions that do work, but I don't know if there are more recent ones (with fewer bugs) available. I did not find any way to download old versions from Sysinternals website. `:-(`

So here is my list (re-checked with a fully patched Windows 2000 box):

```
                            Does not work           Works
    Coreinfo.exe            2.00                    ?
    disk2vhd.exe            1.5.0.0                 ?
    livekd.exe              3.14                    3.0
    procdump.exe            1.72                    ?
    Procmon.exe             2.8 (Frequent crashes)  Filemon/Regmon 7.04
    ShellRunas.exe          1.01                    ?
    vmmap.exe               2.62                    2.2
    ZoomIt.exe              4.1                     1.21
```

If you know of any more recent versions (preferrably with download links) that work on Windows 2000, or an official download link for older versions, it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Some of the newer tools (e.g. `procdump`) may have never worked on Win2k.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below are snapshots before the takeover by Microsoft. Hope this helps, but to be honest, you probably aren't going to find modern sysinternal tools that work with W2k.

- http://court.shrock.org/sysinternals/
- http://court.shrock.org/sysinternals-bt/

Comment: Those links are dead!

Answer (score 12):

Process Monitor 2.80 can be downloaded from http://web.archive.org/web/20100201154222/http://download.sysinternals.com/Files/ProcessMonitor.zip

It works for me in Windows 2000 SP4 Rollup 1

Comment: That works on win2k for me, thanks!

Comment: Works with 2003 SP2

Answer (score 2):

Here's the old versions of ProcDump:

ProcDump v.5.13:
http://web.archive.org/web/20100201154222/http://download.sysinternals.com/Files/ProcDump.zip

ProcDump v.8.0 (the latest to work on `Windows XP`):
http://web.archive.org/web/20160708090036/http://download.sysinternals.com/files/Procdump.zip

Answer (score 1):

coreinfo, disk2vhd, procdump and shellrunas require XP-specific dependencies and will never run on Windows 2000. Older versions of rest of the tools run and most latest versions as of August 2011 run on Windows 2000 SP4!!

Comment: Do you have a viable alternative to procdump for windows 2000?